# Rearrange column in the rows after deleting some column using reactstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, reactstrap

`{allDashItems?.map((item) => ( <Col {...item.size} key={item.name} className={item.class}> {item.component}{item.location} </Col> ))}`

im rendering list of data in Cols but after deleting  some Col , its not rearranging  and giving this gap between col.

any suggestion how can i solve it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd5uE.jpg)
Thank you in advance

I have tried to sort them OR refreshed the page  but did not works